# Add types in the parameter table when generating document with Stardoc

Tags: bazel

We are trying to use Stardoc when generating documentation for our Bazel macros.
I can get a table generated with parameter descriptions when follow the instruction here:
[Macro/Function documenatation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/stardoc/blob/master/docs/writing_stardoc.md#macro--function-documentation).
But we would also like to add the parameter Type in the table.
According to [DocstringUtils.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/2a4c6e335cbfe43d973b6804798002250a8e806d/src/tools/starlark/java/com/google/devtools/starlark/common/DocstringUtils.java) it seems like we shall write the type in parentheses after the parameter name but before colon, as this example:

another_parameter (unused, mutable): a parameter may be followed
by additional attributes in parenthese

I have seen that it's possible to add a rule template to the stardoc() rule (attribute: func_template).
I started to use an own copy of the default template to play around with: //stardoc:templates/markdown_tables/func.vm

If I have understood correctly it doesn't seem that the attributes that I add in paranthese is fetched.
And I don't think that I will be able to retreive that information by just updating the template.
So I think that it will need an update in the Stardoc code for this, correct?!
Is that something that is already planned?
If I'm not correct then I would appreciate information how I can retreive the value of the attribute.

Thanks!

Best Regards
Elisabeth